# Ubuntu Tips applet not working in 11.10

Tags: indicator

I have downloaded the Ubuntu Tips applet .deb from [here](http://gudulin.ru/ubuntutips.html) and installed it. But I am not getting any indicator. When I tried to run it from termial I am getting following error

```
spv@matrix:(~)$ /usr/share/ubuntu-tips-applet/ubuntu-tips-applet.py 

(ubuntu-tips-applet.py:4695): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",

(ubuntu-tips-applet.py:4695): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",

(ubuntu-tips-applet.py:4695): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",

(ubuntu-tips-applet.py:4695): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/ubuntu-tips-applet/ubuntu-tips-applet.py", line 13, in <module>
    import gnome.ui
ImportError: No module named gnome.ui
```

Please tell me how can I get it working on 11.10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install `python-gnome2` which provide `gnome.ui` module. I guess that should work.

So do

`sudo apt-get install python-gnome2`

Answer (score 2):

After reading [this](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2011/01/get-random-ubuntu-tips-on-your-desktop-app/) article, I realised the tips are just a fortune data file.

So you could:

- Install `indicator-fortune` from my [PPA];(https://launchpad.net/~thebernmeister/+archive/ubuntu/ppa)
- Install `fortunes-ubuntu-server`;
- In the preferences for `indicator-fortune` either add the fortunes directory, `/usr/share/games/fortunes` which will add *all* installed fortunes, or specifically add the file `/usr/share/games/fortunes/ubuntu-server-tips.dat`.